# Order of some automorphism in $\mathcal{Q}_8$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $\phi$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{Q}_8$ satisfying $$\phi(i)=-i,\quad \phi(j)=-k.$$ Find the order of $\phi$.

---

So I know that, by definition, we must find the smallest $n$ such that $\phi^n(x)=id$ where $\phi^n$ denotes the composition of $\phi$ with itself $n$ times.

So my attempted answer went a bit wrong. So I guess a hint even at this stage is what I need.

Comment: "So then, I know that the order of $\psi(g)$ divides the order of $g$ where $\psi$ is an arbitrary homomorphism. So, since the order of $i$ is $4$, I know that the order of $\phi$ must either be $1,2$  or $4$." You're mixing up the order of $\phi$ with the order of $\phi(g)$.

Comment: Ah...damn. So back to the drawing board then.

Comment: Why do you think that it can't be $2$?

Comment: @DerekHolt I think that's a symptom of the same issue that I pointed out.

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: @Shaun ignoring the fact that this question has been resolved... the attempt is in the edit history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to repeatedly compose $\phi$ with itself until you get the identity function. Note that $\phi(-1)$ must be $-1$ (you should be able to give a reason for this being the case).

$$\phi^2(i) = \phi(\phi(i)) = \phi(-i) = \phi(-1)\phi(i) = (-1)(-i)=i,$$
$$\phi^2(j) = \phi(\phi(j)) = \phi(-k) = \phi(-ij) = (-1)(-i)(-k) = -ik=j.$$

Is this the identity function? If so the order is 2. If not you need to keep going.